# Requirements for BaseCustomLayer in ArcScene?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

What must be implemented/included to add a layer deriving from BaseCustomLayer to ArcScene?

I have had success adding a BaseCustomLayer to ArcMap by implementing Draw, AreaOfInterest, Cached, MaximumScale, MinimumScale, SpatialReference, Visible, and Name. However, when I attempt to add this layer to ArcScene it gives me the error "ArcScene cannot add this layer".

Comment: Are you talking about the Base Layer In ArcGIS 10?

Comment: I think he's talking about implementing a Custom Layer using the BaseCustomLayer class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try deriving from [BaseCustomGlobeLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/00020000255q000000/) instead?

**Update:** I just tried that and it doesn't work.  I then derived from BaseCustomLayer then implemented [IGraphicsContainer3D](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0009000000pv000000) and was able to add it to the scene without getting an error.

Comment: Isn't that for ArcGlobe only?  Does that work in ArcScene as well?

Comment: I wasn't sure, until I tried. You're right -it does not work with ArcScene.

Comment: IGraphicsContainer3D appears to be the key. Thanks!

Comment: @DBaker Did you get this to work in the end?  I've tried this, and while it adds without error, the behavior is not "clean" whatsoever (ie: graphics from the IGraphicsContainer3D will never remove, etc)...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Looking at [the OMD](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/Arcobjects_net/pdf/3DAnalystObjectModel.pdf) I see that GraphicsLayer3D implements IActiveViewEvents as an outbound interface.  I suspect that [ItemDeleted](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ItemDeleted_Event/0012000001m3000000/) needs to fire when graphics are removed.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I just implemented the entire IActiveViewEvents (and ILayerEvents) and still get the same odd behavior...

Comment: It's not that I'm removing graphics - even setting the layer Visibility to false doesn't cause the items to clear.

Comment: I think that's another issue related to a missing outbound interface.  In arcmap the [featurelayer coclass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FeatureLayerClass_Class/0012000000sv000000/) implements ILayerEvents as an outbound interface.  I suspect the [documentation for graphicslayer3d](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GraphicsLayer3DClass_Class/000900000020000000/) is incorrect and that ILayerEvents should be outbound as it is for featurelayer coclass.

Comment: Looking through the [coclasses that implement ILayerEvents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ILayerEvents_Interface/00120000072w000000/) it appears that all of them do so as an outbound interface (except for globe and 3D layers). A good question would be: How do I implement multiple outbound interfaces for custom classes in C# ?

Comment: Created followup question here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18301/how-do-i-implement-outbound-arcobjects-interfaces-in-c